# (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'cloudsqlproxy~[cloudsql instance ip]' (using password: NO)")

Tags: django, kubernetes

I'm trying to migrate a django app to google kubernetes engine and can't get it to work.

The response from the app is:
Exception Value:
(1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'cloudsqlproxy~[cloudsql instance ip]' (using password: NO)")

If I fire up a bash shell into the running container in which the django app lives, I can connect to the cloud sql instance.

I have my database credentials in environment variables but django doesn't seem to care about the username and password specifically.

django connection settings from inside the container:

```
from django.db import connection
connection.settings_dict
{'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME': 'aesh_db', 'USER': None, 'PASSWORD': None, 'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 'PORT': '3306', 'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}, 'TEST': {'CHARSET': 'utf8mb4', 'COLLATION': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}, 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TIME_ZONE': None}
```

the env vars are set correctly in the container, this works:

```
>> import _mysql
>> import os
>> conn = _mysql.connect(db=os.getenv('DB_NAME'), user=os.getenv('DB_USER'), passwd=os.getenv('DB_PASS'), host=os.getenv('DB_HOST'))
```

django db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASS'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            # Tell MySQLdb to connect with 'utf8mb4' character set
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
         },
        'TEST': {
            'CHARSET': 'utf8mb4',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        }
    }
}
```

deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aesh-web
  labels:
    app: aesh-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aesh-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aesh-web
        image: gcr.io/[my-project]/aesh_web:1.0.0
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
        env:
          - name: LOAD_BALANCER_IP
            value: [service ip]
          - name: DB_HOST
            value: 127.0.0.1
          - name: DB_PORT
            value: "3306"
          - name: DB_NAME
            value: aesh_db
          - name: DB_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: username
          - name: DB_PASS
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: password
      - name: cloudsql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                  "-instances=[instance-connection-name]:aesh-web-db=tcp:3306",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mistery solved, the docker image that the deployment was based on, had an entrypoint script that started the webserver, the env variables specified in the deployment.yaml were set after the entry point script started so django didn't know about them.